# extending the width of bootstrap typeahead to match input field

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I know this question has been asked atleast three times before but the answer I saw were not what I was looking for. I am looking to increase the width of the autocomplete field that twitter bootstrap generates with its typeahead function. I have been reading that it stretches to cover all the text with in the field. that is to say that the longer the text, the wider the autocomplete field. However I would like it to be a span6 because that is how wide my search field is. Any ideas? I have seen some jquery answers but I couldn't follow them.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Michael Watson gave what I think is the simplest answer in his comment.

```
.twitter-typeahead { width: 100%; }
```

**Update #1:** Based on the comments below (thanks Steve, Vishi), do the same for `.tt-hint`, `.tt-input`, `.tt-dropdown-menu`.

**Update #2:** mlissner reports that `.tt-dropdown-menu` is now `.tt-menu`, so the end result is

```
.twitter-typeahead, .tt-hint, .tt-input, .tt-menu { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: I had to do the same for `.tt-hint` as well, but this worked for me.

Comment: I had to make the width of a few more classes 100%.This worked for me `.twitter-typeahead,
.tt-hint,
.tt-input,
.tt-dropdown-menu { width: 100%; }`

Comment: I believe `.tt-dropdown-menu` is now `.tt.-menu`, so the new thing is: `.twitter-typeahead, .tt-hint, .tt-input, .tt-menu { width: 100%; }`. What a mess this is.

Comment: Need to use `!important` to override other styles in my case (I am using Semantic UI)

Answer (score 9):

The dropdown menu is a ul with the classes `typeahead` `dropdown-menu` you could use CSS to set it's width:

```
.dropdown-menu
{
 width: .... px;
}
```

The width of the span6 is not static, so you will need some media queries to make it responsive.

For **Bootstrap 3** the typeahead function is remove from TB3 instead use https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/. <strike>You will need some [additional CSS](https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css) to integrate it with Twitter's Bootstrap.</strike>You'll need to load some additional CSS in order to get the `typeahead.js` dropdown menu to fit the default Bootstrap's theme. Try [extended Bootstrap's LESS](https://github.com/bassjobsen/typeahead.js-bootstrap-css) or if your are looking for a more a more extended version try: [typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less](https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less/blob/master/typeahead.less).

The dropdown with is set with the .tt-dropdown-menu class now. In stead of changing the CSS you could also try to set the width dynamic. With typeahead a class of your typeahead input tag:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({})
on('typeahead:opened',function(){$('.tt-dropdown-menu').css('width',$('.typeahead').width() + 'px');});
```

Comment: Thanks. Use $('#yourinput').outerWidth() though to match the input real width

Comment: this solution with .twitter-typeahead{ width: 100%; } worked for me

Comment: @MichaelLWatson +1 for the simple and straight forward solution.

Answer (score 4):

To make the dropdown match the field width you'd want something like this:

```
$(document).on('typeahead:opened', function(event, datum) {
  var width = $(event.target).width();
  $('.tt-dropdown-menu').width(width);
});
```

Small improvement on the above using event.target and a global document listener.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0 with [typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less](https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less) and nested the input in divs like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>my label</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group tt-input-group">
            <input id="mytypeahead" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also needed to add this to my css:

```
.tt-input-group {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure CSS solution:

Since `.dropdown-menu` is positioned absolute, adding `position: relative;` to the div wrapping around your `uib-typeahead` input field and setting `width: 100%;` to your `.dropdown-menu` will fix it.

Your CSS would look something like this:

```
.typeahead-search {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you works fine, except that the long text being suggested is displayed outside the dropdown.

Comment: @AhmedAlAbdulaal If your text needs to be trimmed, add this class to it
`.overflow-ellipsis {
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is for newer versions:

```
.twitter-typeahead, .tt-menu 
{
  display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: this seems to disable the suggestion dropdown disappearing after picking the element

Comment: This works like a charm in BS4 & TypeAhead 0.11.1

My code is slightly different though: .twitter-typeahead, .tt-hint, .tt-input, .tt-menu { width: 100%; display: block}

Just had to remove !important