# Bootstrap Typeahead width with long text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I have 4 inputs which are in `.col-md-3` as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="input1" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="input2" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="input3" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="input4" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the [Typeahead plugin](http://plugins.upbootstrap.com/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead/). My js works such that Typeahead only works on `#input3`:

```
$('#input3').typeahead({
      ajax: '/getdata.php'
});
```

Some of the text which is being returned is very long (e.g. over 300 characters). The problem with this is that it doesn't fit into the Typeahead dropdown box. It "overlaps" the outside of the box like this:

[image]

I've read [extending the width of bootstrap typeahead to match input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957513/extending-the-width-of-bootstrap-typeahead-to-match-input-field) but none of these fix it for me. I'm wondering if they're deprecated solutions.

`Bootstrap` version is **3.3.7**

Comment: Do you have luck with this:
<style>
input {
  width: 100px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
</style>

Comment: No. Doesn't do anything with the width of the dropdown.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276536/typeahead-js-interferes-with-bootstrap-input-groups

Comment: @Andy did you implement bootstrap3 stylesheet for typeahead? https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less.git This should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you add  `overflow-x: hidden;`  (or auto/scroll if you'd like to be able to scroll), that should work?

Hope the `overflow` attribute works for you.

EDIT: after a bit of googling, I found an article that documented that Typeahead has had issues with design [pertains to inputs in particular] during development. there. There is an [article here](http://wsnippets.com/responsive-facebook-style-navigation-bar-people-search-using-ajax-php-mysql-twitter-bootstrap-3/) that notes it at the end and how it fixed it at the end.

> Note: typahead js has design issue while we use it with twitter
>   bootstrap 3. This tutorial i have added that fixes in css and also you
>   must add following jquery script based on input control size
>
> JavaScript
>
> ```
> $('.typeahead.input-sm').siblings('input.tt-hint').addClass('hint-small');
> $('.typeahead.input-lg').siblings('input.tt-hint').addClass('hint-large');
>
> $('.typeahead.input-sm').siblings('input.tt-hint').addClass('hint-small');
> $('.typeahead.input-lg').siblings('input.tt-hint').addClass('hint-large');
> ```

Also found this ['fix' on github](https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less), created by 'hyspace' - typeahead.js/ bootstrap3.less

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/kedkLvqn/) example of the code that the fix is based upon. I forked it to adjust the entries to have long text that in your case would overflow. As you will see, in the typeahead box in the fiddle, instead of extending beyond the box, the text wraps.

Press 'H' in the second box to see an example of this.

(Do note that the fiddle only uses the code that the fix is ***based on*** - I haven't used the typeahead.js-bootless3.less, but I doubt if you have to hard-code the values! Actually, having read the page on github more closely, it's the style more than anything that has been adjusted, rather than the js.)

Comment: you might have to add !important if the overflow is already pre-set in the style..

Comment: @Andy i just noticed your note about widening the width. Hadn't noticed that. I'll remove that. the link to typeahead demo is http://plugins.upbootstrap.com/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.min.js

Comment: @Andy not even with !important? did you add that?

Comment: I've posted a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rL4vrvs0/1/. Frustratingly, it works fine on there, without any modifications at all. If you go to the third input and type in "s" there is a long option. But in my application it's "cutting off" the dropdown so it's the same width as the input. I don't understand it, but guessing it's some other CSS or conflict within my app.

Comment: try adding a wrapper - see this issue also https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/855 and the noted fix - might work?

Comment: @Andy well any joy? I notice you're not using the typeahead 'tt- ' dropdown in your fiddle.. if you adjust it, does it work?

Comment: Nope. I've added a `.wrapper` to the `input` and the appropriate CSS. Makes no difference, in my app. Works ok on the fiddle. It must be something else in the CSS/js of my app that's doing it. I'll continue looking. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149991/discussion-between-andy-and-rachel-gallen).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by adding css style by setting the width to max-content:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  width: max-content;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a CSS style:

```
white-space: normal;
```

Comment: Makes no difference I'm afraid. Other values such as `nowrap` don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue:

```
.tt-menu {
   width: fit-content;
}
```